# Codeigniter Query doesn't return result value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got the following snippet to get some userrights out of the db:

```
    $tmp   = "SELECT REPLACE(group_concat(CAST(".$role." AS CHAR)),',','') AS rights FROM functionrights ORDER BY id ASC";
    $query = $this->CI->db->query($tmp);
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        $row = $query->row(); 
        return $row->rights;
```

This returns nothing. If I execute the statement direct everything is ok?! What is wrong here?

Comment: try to use: `return $query->result();`and then you can manipulate the result

Comment: This returns: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [rights] => ) )

Comment: Examine your raw SQL. Try: print $this->CI->db->last_query; perhaps you have an error in your SQL

Comment: As I mentioned above - if I execute the raw statement via Navicat or Netbeans (SELECT REPLACE(group_concat(CAST(role1 AS CHAR)),',','') AS rights FROM functionrights ORDER BY id ASC) everthing is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$this->CI->db->query` to `$this->db->query`

The `->CI` is not necessary. Also, you have no `}` tag (but that could be just a copy/paste thing).

Besides that: `->row()` returns one result, while `->result()` returns all results.

Comment: Hey, it's a snippet ;-). I use $this->CI because it is a library.

Comment: Please delete this - wrong database where the table values are empty - damn!